# How do I run Unit Tests for .NET Framework 4.7 with Travis-CI?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I try to run the tests for my project in [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.com). My project is structured like this:

```
.
|-- src (.NET Framework 4.7 class library)
|-- test (.NET Core 3.1 unit test project using MSTest)
```

I can't change the project in `./src` to .NET core.

My `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 3.1.200
before_install: cd test
script:
  - dotnet restore
#  - dotnet add package Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net47 --version 1.0.0
  - dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true
```

The second line in the `script` is something I tried but it didn't help.

It would be great if anyone could lead me to a solution for this. Or tell me that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after quite a while I got it working.

The `.travis.yml` has to look like this:

```yaml
language: csharp
mono: latest
dotnet: 3.1.200
before_install:
  - cd src
script:
  - dotnet restore
  - msbuild
  - dotnet test ../tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/tests.dll
```

Explanation:

- We need .Net Core to build the `tests` .NET Core project and Mono to build the `src` .NET 4.7 project.
- It's not possible to use `dotnet build` to build the .NET 4.7 project, instead the `msbuild` command from Mono has to be used.
- The `dotnet test` command does only work, if the path to the `tests.dll` is provided

Additional notes:

- Mono takes a lot of time to install (~7 minutes), which makes the builds slow. Maybe it's worth to look into using the mono docker container instead.